# PASCAL Arrays (choose Common values from within an array and insert it into a variable)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, pascal

Note: This is not a Homework I don't Want an Answer for the Question given here it is given so that you all can get a clearer understanding on what i ask since it's Hard for me to explain it in English, please forgive me and try to understand what I ask.

This was a question in my Sisters ICT Exam Paper, She asked my help to find the answer but I know only a very little Turbo Pascal. I appreciate if you could help. at least how to calculate how many common Values are within an Array and put them to a variable.
Here is the question.

In array T(8) - Year of birth of Employees
In array P(8) - Gender
In array S(8) - Civil Status

Element of array Y with number N - Year of Birth of Employee N
Element of array P with number N - Gender of Employee N
Element of array S with number N - Civil Status of Employee N

P(N) = 0, Female Employee
P(N) = 1, Male Employee

S(N) = 0, Single Employee
S(N) = 1, Married Employee

Find
K = Number of Female Employees in age 55/ Total Number of Women * 100

**What I ask is how to get the the total of a common value in an array(ex: Array=[1,0,0,1,1] there are only 2 0's) to a variable.**

Thanks in Advance

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking for homework help **must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.*** If your *sister* needs help with *her homework*, she should ask here herself and show the work she's done and ask the question.

Comment: I edited the question, I would appreciate if you could provide an answer now. It is a very confusing language for me.

Comment: Use a loop (`for - do`, `repeat - until`, `while - do`) to traverse the array, adding to a counter each time an array element has the value that you are investigating.

Comment: Or, in addition to what Tom says, keep another array for the counters, with an entry for each possible value that can be in the original array.

Comment: @Marco You are right if the intention is to count all values. I understood "*... a common value ...*" as only one interesting value to investigate. Who knows ...

Comment: I used a for-do loop and a counter as Tom said. That was the only understandable way to get the answer so far.  But what I was searching for was checking the value inside the array separately like in python. Where you make the array and you are able to call values directly in the array.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded a Book on Pascal and read it until now and Figured it out at least a little... I post so it might help someone else.
It goes like this, It Can be Wrong but it worked somehow for an extent

```
Program Emp_Details(input, output);
uses crt;

var
Y: Array[1..8] of integer;
P: Array[1..8] of integer;
S: Array[1..8] of integer;

I: integer;
K: real;

YearCheck: integer;
FemaleCount: integer;

begin
 clrscr;
 For I:= 1 to 8 Do
 begin
      Write('Please enter Year of Birth: ');
      Readln(Y[I]);

      Write('Please Enter Gender: ');
      Readln(P[I]);

      if(P[I] = 0) then
           FemaleCount := FemaleCount + 1;


      Write('Please Enter Civil Status: ');
      Readln(S[I]);

      if(Y[I] = 1961) then
       if(P[I] = 0) then
            YearCheck := YearCheck + 1;

 end;

 K := (YearCheck/FemaleCount) * 100;
 Writeln(K);

 Readkey;
end.
```